# template of callable (callback) as class template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, generic-programming

I would like to achieve something like this:

```
template<class IT>
size_t foo(IT begin,IT end) {return end-begin;}  

template<template (class) class FOO>
class BAR
{
  public:
  any_container<any_type> container;
  size_t call_foo
  {
    FOO<any_container<any_type>::iterator>(container.begin(), container.end());
  }
};
```

Moreover, I want to be able to pass function, lambda or function object as `FOO`.
Probably `std::function` should be used here but it is not possible to declare `std::function<size_t(T,T)>` with arbitrary type `T`.
And I definitely don't want to specify type of inner container or its iterator on template BAR argument list.

Is there any way to solve this in elegant way?

Comment: Are you aware of `std::begin` and `std::end`?

Comment: What is the purpose of `foo()` in your example? And what is `any_container`?

Comment: BAR is generic protocol implementation and foo is system dependent low level send or receive implemntation. How std::begin and end can help?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment I think you are looking for something like this:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

struct Sender {

  template<typename Iter>
  std::size_t operator()(Iter begin, Iter end) {
    for(Iter cur = begin; cur != end; ++cur) {
      // your low-level send stuff
    }
    return (end - begin);
  }
};

struct Receiver {

  template<typename Iter>
  std::size_t operator()(Iter begin, Iter end) {
    for(Iter cur = begin; cur != end; ++cur) {
      // your low-level receive stuff
    }
    return (end - begin);
  }
};

template<typename Fn>
struct Bar
{
protected:
  Fn _fn;
public:
  Bar(Fn fn) : _fn(std::move(fn)) { }

  template<typename Container>
  std::size_t call_fn(Container & container)
  {
    return _fn(std::begin(container), std::end(container));
  }
};

template<typename Fn>
auto create_bar(Fn && fn) -> Bar<typename std::remove_reference<Fn>::type> {
  return { std::forward<Fn>(fn) };
}
```

Usage is simple:

```
template<typename Iter>
std::size_t my_foo(Iter begin, Iter end) {
  return (end - begin);
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  typedef typename std::vector<int>::iterator iter;
  // functors
  auto functor = create_bar(Sender());
  // lambdas
  auto lambda = create_bar([](iter begin, iter end) -> std::size_t { return (end - begin); });
  // plain old functions
  auto function = create_bar(&my_foo<iter>);

  std::vector<int> tmp = { 0, 1, 2, 5};

  std::cout << "Functor: " << functor.call_fn(tmp) << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Lambda: " << lambda.call_fn(tmp) << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Function: " << function.call_fn(tmp) << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Live example [here](http://ideone.com/39r9wQ)

Comment: Looks almost ok, but You have to declare iter in order to use with lambda or function. At the other hand: You're declaring wrapper class which is a little complication. I still hope it is possible to make  solution more purely.